# socket.emit doesn't working with flask

Tags: socket.io, flask-socketio

i try to make simple chat app with flask as project so i have page
when user make new chat room the chat room appear to all of other users
so i have this code but socket.emit doesn't work on it
i mean the flask app doesn't  receive the data  here is the code

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function  () {

// Connect to websocket
var socket = io.connect(location.protocol + '//' + document.domain + ':' + location.port+'/channels');


// When connected, configure buttons
socket.on('connect', function () {



    document.querySelector("#create").onclick=function (){

        const new_channel=document.querySelector("#new_chanell").value;
        const channels_list=document.querySelector("#channels");
        for (let i=0; i<channels_list.length;i++){
            if(channels_list[i].value==new_chanell){

                document.querySelector("h1").innerHTML="this channel allready here";
                return false;}
        }
        socket.emit('add_channel', {'channel': new_channel});
        document.querySelector("h1").innerHTML="new channel";


        return false;

}});
```

and in flask

```
@socketio.on("add_channel")
def add_channel(data):
raise("he")
channel=data["channel"]
channel_list.append(channel)
emit("new_one",{"channel":channel},broadcast=True)
```

so i put raise("he") to know if the app receive the data but no
the function doesn't call at all why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the connection URL you are passing a `/channels` namespace. If that is intended, then on the server you have to add the namespace into all your event handlers:

```
@socketio.on("add_channel", namespace='/channels')
def add_channel(data):
    # ...
```